# How to rename a Gitea Site?

Tags: gitea

So, I got a basic Gitea Instance here: https://git.cowdev.online, but I would like to rename my site.
NOTE: It's actually a Nginx server which uses a Gitea Server on port 3000 as a reverse proxy.
If the website goes down, It's most likely I'm just playing with it or my Server trial or Domain ended.
UPDATE: I upgraded to GitLab, So you can't use the link anymore.

Comment: Git is totally uninvolved here. Your web server's site-name determines the site name. This is not part of Git.

Comment: I'm talking about Gitea, not Git

Comment: Yes, but you kept tagging this with [tag:git]. I deleted the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, there's a property in gitea's config file (for me located in /var/snap/gitea/gitea-common/gitea.ini)